# Emacs telnet mode display strange characters

Tags: emacs, telnet

I got strange characters like this when connect to a remote machine using `M-x telnet`:

```
^[[0m^[[00m.bash_history^[[0m  ^[[00m.bashrc^[[0m  ^[[00m.exrc^[[0m  ^[[01;34m.gnupg^[[0m  ^[[01;34m.ssh^[[0m  ^[[01;34mbin^[[0m  ^[[00mtest.rom^[[0m
```

The above is an example of ls. How do I make my Telnet usable?

I use telnet in eshell and it works fine. Everything is displayed correctly. However, I cannot issue escape character to quit telnet. How do I do this?

Edit: I managed to discover that `C-q C-]` provide my needed escape character (I guess `C-q` is Emacs way of escaping characters). But, I still want `M-x telnet` to be usable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. For keep using telnet solution... have you tried `M-x ansi-color-for-comint-mode-on` in the telnet buffer?
2. For the eshell solution, I would try to use `eshell-toggle-direct-send`, and then sending the telnet escape character with C-q C-]

Comment: Thanks for `eshell-toggle-direct-send` suggestion. It is more convenient. About the telnet solution, when I tried some command like `ls`, it produced junk output like above, but after pressing enter it displayed nicely with proper colours. But this is annoying; I will stick with the eshell solution.